# irreducible representation contained in regular rep

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

> Why is every irreducible representation contained in the regular representation?

Suppose $W$ is a irreducible representation. ( i.e. a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ which $G$ acts on with no $G$-invariant subspace)

Then fix $0\neq w\in W$ and define $\mathbb{C}[G]\rightarrow W, \; \sum\alpha_gg \mapsto\sum\alpha_gg(w)$. Hence by irreducibility of $W$, $W$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[G]/(M)$ for some maximal ideal $M$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

But I still can't see why W can be regarded a subspace of $\mathbb{C}[G]$?

Comment: The key fact is that the algeba $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is semisimple, hence every factor of the regular module (regular rep.) is isomorphic to a submodule of $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

Comment: Thanks, after applying some splitting short exact and semisimple property, it is done!

Comment: Just for reference: The result (that for $G$ finite, the algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is semisimple) is called Maschke's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

Looking back at this old answer of mine, I want to improve it.

For $W$ to be irreducible, we mean it has no nonzero proper subrepresentations. If we take any $0 \neq w \in W$, then its orbit $G w$ is a nonzero subrepresentation of $W$, so we must have $W = G w$.

Now since $W$ is a $G$-module, we can regard it as a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module if we extend by linearity.  And there's a natural map of $G$-modules $\mathbb{C}[G] \to W$ given by
$$\left(\sum_i a_i g_i\right) \mapsto \sum_i a_i (g_i \cdot w)$$

We've just seen this map is surjective, so if $I$ is its kernel then by the first isomorphism theorem $W \cong \mathbb{C}[G]/I$.

Now since $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is semisimple, any quotient of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $\mathbb{G}[G]$.

---

**Previous answer**

I'm assuming $G$ is a finite group and $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is the group algebra.

The way I've seen this done is via character theory.  Observing that the regular representation is a permutation representation, we can extract its character.  It follows from character theory that any $k$-dimensional irreducible representation of $G$ appears $k$ times in the regular representation.

Comment: I think I should regard W as a subspace of ℂ[G], therefore it is contained in a regular representation.

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood what you were asking about.  I've edited my answer now.

Comment: I could understand this answer, it is helpful but somehow I am using this fact to build up character theory...

Comment: Are you following a particular text?

Comment: No, I am following my class notes.